# How to convert a nltk tree (Stanford) into newick format in python?

Tags: python, tree, nltk

I have this Stanford tree and I want to convert this into newick format.

```
    (ROOT
     (S
        (NP (DT A) (NN friend))
        (VP
         (VBZ comes)
         (NP
           (NP (JJ early))
           (, ,)
           (NP
             (NP (NNS others))
             (SBAR
                (WHADVP (WRB when))
                (S (NP (PRP they)) (VP (VBP have) (NP (NN time))))))))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be ways to do this just using string processing, but I would parse them and print them in the newick format recursively. A somewhat minimal implementation:

```
import re

class Tree(object):
    def __init__(self, label):
        self.label = label
        self.children = []

    @staticmethod
    def _tokenize(string):
        return list(reversed(re.findall(r'\(|\)|[^ \n\t()]+', string)))

    @classmethod
    def from_string(cls, string):
        tokens = cls._tokenize(string)
        return cls._tree(tokens)

    @classmethod
    def _tree(cls, tokens):
        t = tokens.pop()
        if t == '(':
            tree = cls(tokens.pop())
            for subtree in cls._trees(tokens):
                tree.children.append(subtree)
            return tree
        else:
            return cls(t)

    @classmethod
    def _trees(cls, tokens):
        while True:
            if not tokens:
                raise StopIteration
            if tokens[-1] == ')':
                tokens.pop()
                raise StopIteration
            yield cls._tree(tokens)

    def to_newick(self):
        if self.children and len(self.children) == 1:
            return ','.join(child.to_newick() for child in self.children)
        elif self.chilren:
            return '(' + ','.join(child.to_newick() for child in self.children) + ')'
        else:
            return self.label
```

Note that, of course, information gets lost during the conversion, since only terminal nodes are kept. Usage:

```
>>> s = """(ROOT (..."""
>>> Tree.from_string(s).to_newick()
...
```

Comment: I copied it almost verbatim from my [file of various nlp functions](https://github.com/L3viathan/toolib/blob/master/nlp.py) (might be useful if you're working with parse trees), just had to add `to_newick`.

Comment: Sorry, but I did not understand you!! I copied your code but it does not work :(

Comment: I got this error when I try to traverse tree 'ete2.parser.newick.NewickError: Empty leaf node found'.

Comment: I would guess because of the comma? Does it work if you take `(, ,)` out of the initial string?

Comment: Exactly, the problem is punctuation marks. i will do that. Thank you =)

Comment: The problem is with commas specifically, because in the newick format, a comma seperates the nodes, so it doesn't see the comma as a node itself. There might be a way to escape them (maybe by putting them in quotes?), but that depends on your parser. Side question: Why are you using the ETE toolkit? I've never used it, but it seems to be mostly for phylogenetic trees.